# Vine like video recording with PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to develop an iPhone application just like [Vine](https://vine.co/) using PhoneGap. PhoneGap 2.7 doesn't support duration control so I switched to PhoneGap 3.0. It supports duration control but I can't implement the touch to capture option.

Does anybody know how to customize video recording by altering the plugin? Is it possible to create a pause option during recording and set a 6 sec limit? How can I get better control using the PhoneGap plugin?

Comment: Have you got any success regarding this....???

Comment: No.. I have Switched my project to native. There is no possibility to do that.@vishnu

Comment: you should offer a bounty here

Comment: This should be completely possible with a plugin. You'd just need to build it yourself.

Comment: yeah may be possible.... but i tried it by simply create a javascript interface to connect my custom camera  But i didn't satisfied with that...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the VideoCapturePlus plugin.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/VideoCapturePlus-PhoneGap-Plugin

It allows a time limit and png video overlays which may be useful. It needs some tweaks to allow pausing the video, but it looks like there is something similar commented out in the source code. It may be worth contacting the developer for clarity.